# mount error in android terminal emulator: ioctl loop_set_fd failed device or resource busy

Tags: android, linux, mount, ioctl

I am using PuTTY to open up a SSH terminal to my Android phone which has BusyBox 1.21.1 installed. I was trying to mount an ISO image with the following command in the terminal, mind the fact that I was already in superuser mode and my phone is rooted and this similar approach works like a charm in my Ubuntu 12.04 machine:

```
mount -o ro,loop -t cdfs slitaz-4.0.iso temp/mntpnt
```

Comment: While it may not be your first problem, do you have any evidence that your device's kernel supports this filesystem?  I can't really think of any reason why it would.

Comment: Seemingly no. Any idea how can I fix that?

The mount command in android is acting pretty weird, as are most of the other commands e.g. when df -h is typed into the terminal "-h is not a file or filesystem" where as df -h is sorta common implementation of df!

Comment: Android is quite differentvfrom a normal linux, with its own limited tools.  For the filesystem you'd probably have to build and load a kernel driver  or else interpret it in userspace without actually mounting.